# FBWebDialog passing params to FB app page?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-apps, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am using the FB iOS SDK to invite friends to my app.   I am able to use the FBWebDialog to post the "Invite" which shows up in the recipients notifications.  The link then redirects that recipient to the Facebook app page for my app.    The FB app page currenly embeds my website.

```
    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                              message:@"Try this app called ..."
                                                title:@"Invite to ..."
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                      // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                                                      NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                                                  } else {
                                                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                          // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                                                          NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                                                      } else {
                                                          NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                                                      }
                                                  }}];
```

In a perfect world I would like to pass a parameter to the app homepage so I can redirect to the appropiate detail page in my site.  Is this possible?

Thanks